# Cannot find a version of 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin

I've been following the Test Navigation Components unit from Android Basics in Kotlin course:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-basics-kotlin-test-navigation-components#4

I'm trying to write a test for navigation components and getting the following error when Android Studio tries to run the test:

```
Cannot find a version of 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'WordsV2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.3.5' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:[2.3.5]'
   Dependency path 'WordsV2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.0.0'
   Dependency path 'WordsV2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.0.0'
   Constraint path 'WordsV2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
   Constraint path 'WordsV2:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime' strictly '2.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.words"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.3.5"

    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.6'
}
```

I also use Android Studio version 3.3.1 (Jan 2019) because I'm limited to MacOs High Sierra (v10.13.6).

Comment: You can't mix Navigation 2.0.0 and 2.3.5. Have you tried using Navigation 2.3.5 for every one of your Navigation dependencies?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks. Changing the Navigation dependencies all to 2.3.5 solved the problem.